# jQuery chosen - on click dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using chosen JQuery plugin, i would like when the user click on the select box; do something (load data from data base into the select box).

**HTML**

```
<select name="mysection" id="mysection" class="chosen-select-deselect">
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('#mysection').live('click',function(){             
alert("hello for test");             
})
```

I tried to just test if the event work or not, but it seems not working

NB: i'm using jquery 1.6.4

Comment: I would recommend you to upgrade to latest version of jQuery soon!

Comment: What is your console saying? Any error log? Can you provide a fiddle, because this should work. And yeap you should update you jQuery library

Comment: Upgrade to a newer jquery...   Also, what does your console say?  Is it showing any problems?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker that wont work he is in 1.6.4

Comment: there is no problem in the console !!

Comment: try `.live("change"` instead of click.

Comment: i'm working with .live("change" , but they ask to chaneg the event on click instead of on change.

Comment: then you need to attach `click` event to `option` not select itself, which isn't possible I assume.

Comment: of course it won't work. if you attach `click` to selectmenu, it'll trigger event once clicked. so your solution is `change`, its up to you.

Comment: @Omar  My select box look like this <select name="mysection" id="mysection" data-placeholder="Choisissez la section..." style="width:400px;" class="chosen-select-deselect" tabindex="1">  and when i remove class="chosen-select-deselect" from my select box this code : $('#mysection').click(function(){
      alert('hello');
      });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47747/discussion-between-omar-and-mehdi-boussarhane)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While dealing with the selectmenus or check boxes use '`change`'.

here is the code

**HTML**

```
<select name="mysection" id="mysection">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mysection").chosen();
    $('#mysection').live('change', function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#mysection {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Try the above code, it will work :)

**EDIT**

when you use chosen, it converts select into another div after it, you can even use

```
$("#mysection_chosen").bind("click", function ()
```

or

```
$("#mysection").next().bind('click', function ()
```

Comment: I already work with .live('change' and it's work fine. but my need is related to the .live('click' . because i want to load data into the select box one time the user click on it